# Null pointer exception when SimpleDateFormate parsing?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, time-format

I have this method that is supposed to take the difference between two times but I keep getting a null pointer exception on the first line of code in the try block.

The time parameter takes in the time of the function call in "HH:mm:ss" format, and both time1 and time2 are global string variables with "HH:mm:ss" formats.

```
private String calculateTime(String time) {
        time2 = time;

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        Date date1;
        Date date2;
        try {
             date1 = timeFormat.parse(time1);
             date2 = timeFormat.parse(time2);
             long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
             time1 = timeFormat.format(new Date(diff));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("The diff is "+ time1);

        return time1;

    }
}
```

I've stepping through the code and everything seems to be set up correctly, it's only when it gets to `date1 = timeFormate.parse(time1)` that it seems to not work. Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Aside from the null pointer exception, this is going to go badly wrong when you convert your difference in milliseconds back into a `Date`.  A difference between two dates doesn't make sense as a `Date`.  This is a really bad thing to try to do.

Comment: What is `time1`? Where is it declared? And initialized?

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

time1 is being initialized after you're referencing it. It's clear from the code you've posted. Time2 is assigned to time but time1 is never initialized before the reference.

Comment: time1 is  already initialized prior to this method call @jason

Comment: @david Obviously not, otherwise it wouldn't be `null`. --- If you believe it is not null, prove it to us. Insert print statements to print `time1` and `time2` *right before* the calls to `parse()`. Then show us the program output, including the full stacktrace from the NullPointerException you say you get from that non-null value you say `time1` has.

Comment: lol ok here is variables shown from the debugger https://i.gyazo.com/8097f18a4d2d204628f863776a92546f.png
either way i  figured out how to fix it, thanks anyways

Comment: @Andreas you sound really angry.

Comment: @david Sorry, I asked for the printed output and a **full stacktrace**. You should **edit** the question and add that to your question, to clarify it. --- Better yet, edit the question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Nope. Not angry at all.